# Exporting Account Name, Domain & Timestamp from Security Auditing Event Log

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I am currently exporting the last 7 days of Security microsoft windows security auditing logs via powershell to csv.

It works, but with way to much detail, and also, not properly formatted. For instance, from the csv, the 'message' cell has this in

> "An account was successfully logged on.
>
> Subject:  Security ID:        X   Account Name:       -   Account Domain:     -
>     Logon ID:       0x0
>
> Logon Type:           3
>
> Impersonation Level:      Impersonation
>
> New Logon:    Security
>   ID:       X   Account
>   Name:     XXX Account Domain:     XXX Logon ID:       XXX     Logon
>   GUID:     {XXX}
>
> Process Information:  Process ID:     0x0     Process Name:       -
>
> Network Information:  Workstation Name:   -   Source Network
>   Address:  XXX.XXX     Source Port:        XXX
>   ............

Now to get the above into csv i am using this powershell script

```
[xml]$CustomView = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID=4624 or EventID=4672 or EventID=4648 or EventID=463) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]]] </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

Get-WinEvent -FilterXML $CustomView | Export-CSV "C:\CustomView_$(Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-DD").csv"
```

How is it possible to export a csv with the following columns?

Event Id, Security ID, Account Name, Account Domain, Logon ID, Logon, TimeCreated

Comment: You would need to parse the message field to get the data that you wanted then export that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details from the event message body are stored in the event XML. You can convert the event to XML and then extract each of the XML fields. The thing to keep in mind is that you should only query multiple event IDs when they share a common schema, otherwise the event properties may not be consistent in the output. There is a good write-up explaining the process and event schema issue [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/08/28/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs/).

There is a cmdlet on GitHub called [Get-WinEventData](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-WinEventData.ps1) that does all the heavy lifting for you. The output contains properties for all the main event fields like machine name, provider name, and message. It also contains properties for all of the XML event data. To use this, simply pipe your Get-WinEvent command into Get-WinEventData, select the properties you want, then export to CSV. Of course you will need to import the Get-WinEventData function beforehand.

Example usage:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security";Id=4624,4672;StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Get-WinEventData | Select-Object TimeCreated,Id,EventDataSubjectUserSid,EventDataSubjectUserName,EventDataSubjectDomainName,EventDataSubjectLogonId | Export-CSV "Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're very welcome :)